# Guardar Cuenta Atrás

Tags: android

Estuve buscando mucho cómo hacer para que mi cuenta atrás continúe cuando cierro la aplicación y encontré 2 opciones: Una crear un service pero no entiendo bien que es y la otra, calcular la diferencia del tiempo transcurrido cuando vuelvo a abrir la aplicación.

Pensaba iniciar un cronómetro cuando la aplicación se cierre y luego al volver a abrirla calcular la diferencia y que retome la cuenta atrás. Pero no sé bien si se hace en el `onDestroy`, `onStop` o `onPause`.

Este es el código de la cuenta atrás que hice:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu
        // this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void a(View view){
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv1.setText("La cuenta llega a 0 en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                tv1.setText("Listo!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Un `IntentService` podría serte de utilidad.

Puedes crearlo seleccionado tu paquete java en el proyecto, presionar click derecho y seleccionar **New > Service > Service (Intent Service)**.

Esto agregará el componente en el **AndroidManifest.xml** y creará una plantilla prefabricada con los controladores necesarios para que funcione de forma básica el servicio.

Todo lo que vayas a realizar va en `onHandleIntent()`.

*Por ejemplo...*

> El siguiente servicio cuenta hacia atrás desde 10 hasta 1, en
>    intervalos de 1 segundo de espera.
>
> Además de ello crea una notificación de usuario para ponerlo en primer
>   plano y evitar su cierre por el usuario.

**ProgressIntentService.java**

```
public class ProgressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = ProgressIntentService.class.getSimpleName();


    public ProgressIntentService() {
        super("ProgressIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
                handleActionRun();            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Maneja la acción de ejecución del servicio
     */
    private void handleActionRun() {
        try {
            // Se construye la notificación
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
                    .setContentTitle("Servicio en segundo plano")
                    .setContentText("Procesando...");

            // Bucle de simulación
            for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {

                Log.d(TAG, i + ""); // Logueo

                // Poner en primer plano
                builder.setProgress(10, i, false);
                startForeground(1, builder.build());


                // Retardo de 1 segundo en la iteración
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            // Quitar de primer plano
            stopForeground(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad :).

Si deseas aprender más sobre como usar servicios te dejo esta guía:

[Tutorial Para Crear Un Servicio En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/)

Answer (score 0):

- Si se debe detener el tiempo únicamente cuando se cierra la aplicación debe ser en **`onStop()`**
- Si contemplas que se debe detener el tiempo cuando envías la aplicación a background sería en **`onPause()`**